# Show that a plane wave satisfies: $µ \frac{∂^2y}{∂t^2} = T \frac{∂^2y}{∂x^2} − α \frac{∂^4y}{∂x^4}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I am unsure how to go about this question and I would appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: Where I would start: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave

Comment: How is this off-topic? they admitted they didn't know where to start, so i helped them start it. See the comments of my answer below that demonstrate this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that a generic plane wave, $y(x,t)$, solves this equation:

$$ \mu \frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial t^{2}} = T \frac{\partial^{2}y}{\partial x^{2}} − \alpha \frac{\partial^{4}y}{\partial x^{4}}  $$

Of course, since this is your homework problem I will only set you in the right direction, but won't solve it for you :)

A generic two dimensional plane wave (one time dimension and one spatial dimension) can be written as,

$$ y(x,t) = A_{o} cos(kx - \omega t + \phi)$$

where $A_{o}$ is the amplitude, $k$ is the wave number, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, and $\phi$ is the constant phase shift of the wave.

Now, what you want to do is show algebraically that when you plug in $y(x,t)$ into the given partial differential equation the two sides equal each other. So, it's simplest to calculate each derivative in the equation separately (to avoid mistakes), and then use those derivatives to construct the equation (multiply the correct derivatives with the coefficients $\mu, T, \alpha$), then show that the two sides of the equation equal the same thing (show that the equal sign is indeed true). Then you're done! Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: So I have worked out the partial derivatives and I now have μ(-ω² Acos(kt-ωx+ϕ)) = T(-k²A cos(kt-ωx+ϕ)) - α(k⁴A cos(kt-ωx+ϕ)), and so I have μω²= Tk² + αk⁴, I don't know what μ,T,α are so I don't know how to show that it is true.

Comment: Why in the h*** was my answer downvoted???? What the..... this is why people should be forced to comment when downvoting.....

Comment: @Plzhelpme So, I think you can express $\omega$ in terms of $k$

Comment: I have done so as the next part of the question asks for the phase and group velocities, which I know how to do once I have ω(k). So it's sufficient to just show that ω(k) can be expressed in terms of k to show it fits the wave equation? Thanks.

Comment: My great pleasure. Please do me a favor and accept the answer as correct by clicking the check mark by my answer.

Comment: And in fact, what you've done is found the dispersion relation for this wave equation, which is $\omega (k)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation